# How to ensure index creation using the correct template?

Tags: elasticsearch

Here come 2 questions:

I have a few templates set in elasticsearch, and also have set their template match pattern.

1. On creation of the index, is there a way to specify the template on creation of the index?
2. After creation of the index, is there a way for me to check that the creation of the index has used which templates?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. On creation of the index, is there a way to specify the template on creation of the index?

No, this is why you need to provide the right matching patterns for your templates, plus the right ordering if you have many that apply to the same index name.

> 2. After creation of the index, is there a way for me to check that the creation of the index has used which templates?

Yes, but you need the logs for that. Elasticsearch will usually log (I think only on the elected master node), a line saying something like this:

```
[o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [node_name] [testingnow] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], templates [whatever], shards [5]/[1], mappings [_default_]
```

The relevant piece there is **templates [whatever]** which shows which templates were used at index creation time.

Comment: For #2, apart from low log level, can I verify from dev console in kibana?

Comment: You could look at the mapping of the resulting index and see if there is anything specific to a certain template in there... there's no simple way out.